# How do i assign a multiline string to a variable using python and while displaying with \n at end of each line

Tags: python-2.7

I have a yaml file where i have assigned

apple: "iamafruit
iamtasty
iamhealthy"

in my python file

a = apple
print a

iamafruit iamtasty iamhealthy

but i want to be displayed as

iamfruit\n
iamtasty\n
iamhealthy

Comment: how do i assign a multiline string to a variable

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Python [tutorial section on strings](https://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

For a string literal to span multiple lines, you can end each line with a continuation character, a backslash:

```
a = "apple\n\
tasty\n\
healthy"
```

or you can use the triple-quotes:

```
a = """apple
tasty
healthy"""
```

If your string is short, and you don't care about readability, you can just include the newline characters, like this:

```
a = "apple\ntasty\nhealthy"
```

To combine several lines (strings), you can also use `str.join()` on the newline character:

```
a = '\n'.join(['apple', 'tasty', 'healthy'])
```

Any of these methods will produce:

```
>>> print(a)
apple
tasty
healthy
```

If you have a list of words which you wish to convert to a multiline string, use you can use `str.split()` in combination with `str.join()`:

```
apple = "apple tasty healthy"
lines = '\n'.join(apple.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apply = "iamafruit iamtasty iamhealthy"
apple = apple.replace(" ", "\n ")
print apple
```

now apply will be

```
apple = "iamafruit\n iamtasty\n iamhealthy"
```